# Is there any example on how to write test for CRUD based app in "Laravel 5.1"?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, tdd, laravel-5.1

I am somewhat experienced with the php's Laravel framework.

In it's new version (5.1) they have massively improved their testing features.

Is there any example of how to write tests for a basic CRUD app in laravel 5.1.

I was able to test the creation of tasks. But still I am not sure if it is the best practice. Please help me.

```
<?php

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class TasksTest extends TestCase
{    
    use DatabaseTransactions;    
    public function testCreateTask()
    {
        $this->visit('/tasks/create')
             ->type('This is task title', 'title')
             ->type('This is task description', 'description')
             ->press('Create Task')
             ->seePageIs('/tasks')
             ->see('This is task title');
    }    
}
```

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/laracasts/integrated

Answer (score -3):

First of all just add crud library in your project and then,
just simply run this command,

php artisan crud:generate crud-name --fields="name:string, email:string, phone:integer, message:text"

Comment: The question is about tests not the actual CRUD